# How to keep my application from being suspended

Tags: visual-studio

I have an application in Visual Studio that when I run it in Visual Studio, it never gets suspended. But when I run the application outside of Visual Studio, it gets suspended. What does Visual Studio do to my application that keeps it from being suspended.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by “suspended”?  What kind of application?  Language? Visual Studio version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.